# Entity Framework 5 and Char Enums

Tags: entity-framework, enums, char, entity-framework-5

Can entity framework 5 handle char enums?  I have it working with an int, but with a char I get the error below where the column in the database is char(1).

```
The 'Gender' property on 'Division' could not be set to a 'String' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Gender'.

public enum Gender
{
    Male = 'M',
    Female = 'F'
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your enum type is not of char type but of int type. The following line will show you that:

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(Gender).GetEnumUnderlyingType());

System.Int32
Press any key to continue . . .
```

The values of your enum members are actually 77 and 70 respectively:

```
Console.WriteLine((int)Gender.Male);
Console.WriteLine((int)Gender.Female);

77
70
Press any key to continue . . .
```

The only valid underlying types of enum types in C#/VB.NET are byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int, uint, long and ulong. If you try putting an underlying type that is not on this list like this:

```
public enum Gender : char
{ 
    Male = 'M', 
    Female = 'F' 
}
```

You will see the following compilation error:

```
error CS1008: Type byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, or ulong expected
```

This is the theory behind enums in C#. Now the EF part - EF currently suports only the following underlying types for enums: Edm.Byte, Edm.SByte, Edm.Int16, Edm.Int32 and Edm.Int64 (the Edm type system does not have unsigned types). For enums properties the corresponding column in the database must match the underlying type of the enum type of the property (i.e. if your the underlying type of your enum property is Edm.Int32 then the column should be of int type).

In your case - if you really want to go with your enum type your column in the database should be of int type. You should expect to see values of 70 and 77 in the column when you add entities.

Comment: SqlServer doesn't appear to support SByte, I'm not sure if other databases do. It does mean that you cant use enum : sbyte as a type when interfacing with MSSQL

Comment: This answer is EF specific and not Sql Server specific - from EF point of view sbyte is a valid underlying type for enum types. You are correct with regards to Sql Server where sbyte type does not work.

Answer (score 0):

This is my first time using EF and I started with EF5. So when I tried to fix this issue, I ended up here. There were very confusing answers elsewhere but the one that seems the most obvious to me was the one below.

I do hope this is accurate but seems to work fine for me.

I imported my DB from Postgres

In your context, there is a space where you can define your columns where they need to map to a different name than your variable name or things like that.

You can have a conversion in this space.  See the blog below for a better explanation.

https://blog.bitscry.com/2019/07/29/converting-a-char-character-to-an-enum-in-entity-framework/

Mine is a bit more complex than it needs to be.

This is my table with the enumiration

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DevDBStub.Models.DB
{
    public class PreparationScreen
    {
        public enum CompleteMethods
        {
            Button = 'B',
            Timer  = 'T'
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Descr { get; set; }
        public int NumberOfColumns { get; set; }
        public CompleteMethods CompleteMethod { get; set; }
        public int TimerSeconds { get; set; }
        public string DoneBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime TmStamp { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now for my context

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;

#nullable disable

namespace DevDBStub.Models.DB
{
    public partial class ReactContext : DbContext
    {
        public ReactContext()
        {
        }

        public ReactContext(DbContextOptions<ReactContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<PreparationProfile> PreparationProfiles { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.HasAnnotation("Relational:Collation", "en_ZA.UTF-8");


            modelBuilder.Entity<PreparationScreen>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("preparationscreen");

                entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("id");

                entity.Property(e => e.CompleteMethod)
                    .HasConversion<char>(p => (char)p, p => (PreparationScreen.CompleteMethods)p)
                    .HasColumnName("completemethod");

                entity.Property(e => e.Descr)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .HasColumnName("descr");

                entity.Property(e => e.DoneBy)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(16)
                    .HasColumnName("doneby");

                entity.Property(e => e.NumberOfColumns).HasColumnName("numberofcolumns");

                entity.Property(e => e.TimerSeconds).HasColumnName("timerseconds");

                entity.Property(e => e.TmStamp).HasColumnName("tmstamp");
            });
        }

        partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is the "HasColumnType"?